# Is it possible to produce a final SHA-256 value from a series of intermediate values?

Tags: javascript, c#

Is it possible to produce multiple intermediate SHA-256 values that could somehow be combined at a later time to produce the same SHA-256 that would be produced from a single hashing computation?

In other words, if I hash a 4GB .ISO image file for a SHA-256 value one day, could I produce the same single SHA-256 by splitting the file into, lets say 10 sections, producing an intermediate SHA-256 for each section, and then at a later time, produce the final SHA-256 using "only" the intermediate SHA-256 values?

I realise there is probably no way to produce 10 intermediate SHA-256 values from 1 final SHA-256 value but I thought it might be possible to hash a file in chunks and combine those 10 intermediate SHA-256 values at a later time without needing the actual data at the same time.

If this is possible, how would I produce the final SHA-256 from the intermediate SHA-256 values in C# and/or JavaScript?

**Edit:** I want to take away the requirement of the intermediate values being SHA-256 values.

I don't care what they are as long as I can produce a final SHA-256 at a later time using "only" the multiple intermediate values and no data. And have it be the exact same SHA-256 that I would have gotten doing it all at once on the 4GB(arbitrary size) file.

I'm thinking of something like a voucher system where the conductor asks to see your train ticket and you have some person step up in your place and say, "I've already checked this guy out, you don't need to, I will verify his integrity".

Answer (score 0):

A hashing algorithm produces a unique hash for every input data. Any combination of the intermediate hashes is still different from your ISO file, thus producing a different hash than if you would hash the file directly.

If you drop the requirement that the hash produced from the file must be the same as the final hash produced from the intermediates, you can still use the later approach in my opinion since the combination of 10 hashes should still be unique in and of itself, giving a unique final hash for each input file.

The scheme could look something like that:

[image]

Comment: I really need the final SHA-256 value of the single file but I wanted to calculate that value in pieces so it was less harsh on system resources. Basically calculating a SHA-256 in stages. I have no idea how you would do this on a single file so I thought splitting the files, producing intermediate values, and using those values to produce a final SHA-256 would be easiest on system resources.

Comment: @Bradley As I said, you can do that but the final hash will be different than hashing the complete file directly. That's the core definition of a hash function: Same input-->same output, different input (even a single bit)-->dramatically different output. Its not like calculating the overall sum of all bytes for example, where you could sum up different parts and then take the sum of these intermediate sums. That's not how hash functions work.

Comment: Okay, my idea had good intentions but after more thought it does seem to be impossible. Hashing "hashes" and not the final bits proves only the integrity of the individual split files and nothing of the final file as a whole. It seems the act of hashing "hashes" only provides a snapshot of a group of files integrity at a given point in time and nothing about the possible "current" state of those files. If you hash stale hashes, your source files could still have been tampered with. So thank you for your input. After much thought, I am rejecting my own idea as no good.

Comment: @Bradley If you always concatenate the individual hashes in the same way before hashing again, the final hash will be unique for the source file as well. If anything in the source file is changed, that intermediate hash will be changed, thus changing the final hash as well.

Comment: Oh, you are suggesting concatenation of all intermediate hashes to produce a final value and then doing a string comparison? But that wouldn't necessarily be considered a SHA-256 hash then would it? Or, when you say concatenation, do you mean to "feed" the reproducable hashes into a SHA-256 function as the "seed" for reach interaction, so to speak? That could be done but then I don't see the savings in time. It digresses into a hashing of the entire file as a whole.

Comment: No you concatenate the byte arrays you get from SHA256'ing the parts into one large array and SHA256 that again to produce the final hash. You could parallelize the computation of the SHA256 hash for the individual parts, thus maybe saving some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84718/discussion-between-bradley-and-jens).

Comment: @Bradley I visualized what I mean.